# python распарсить json с ozon

Tags: python, json

Всем привет.
Есть json, который получаю с ozon. Мне нужно получить остатки на складах. Этот json находится в HTML страницы корзины. (нужно добавить товар в корзину и перейти в нее). Других способов найти эти данные видимо нет. Ну уж очень какой то сложный, как я над ним и он надо мной уже не издевался, не могу распарсить.
Вот, на чем остановился:

```
tracking_payloads = text.find('trackingPayloads')
s = text[tracking_payloads:].replace('trackingPayloads":', '').\
    replace('\\n', '').\
    replace('\\\\"', "'").\
    replace('\\"', '\\\\"')
print(s)
```

Но в некоторых местах появляются лишние закрывающие фигурные скобки.
Нужно какое то может универсальное решение, так как озон часто меняет содержимое.
Помогите, пожалуйста, отблагодарю.
Сам json: https://pastebin.com/EiXE4mT2
Нужно получить это:

```
{'type':'group','title':'Доставка Ozon','department':'ozon','isAvailable':true,'objects':[{'type':'delivery','deliveryType':'pickup','minOrderAmount':0,'minOrderAmountLack':0}],'items':[{'sku':539033151,'finalPrice':2256,'originalPrice':2256,'quantity':1,'maxQuantity':6,'checked':true,'bundleId':'','unavailableReason':'UnavailableReason_None','storehouseId':220579,'availableDeliverySchema':[221],'selectedDeliverySchema':221,'isServicesAvailable':false,'isFastDelivery':false,'multiplicity':0,'marketplaceId':1},{'sku':176331186,'finalPrice':799,'originalPrice':1390,'quantity':1,'maxQuantity':10,'checked':true,'bundleId':'','unavailableReason':'UnavailableReason_None','storehouseId':660,'availableDeliverySchema':[131,111],'selectedDeliverySchema':111,'isServicesAvailable':false,'isFastDelivery':true,'multiplicity':0,'marketplaceId':1}]}
```

Ну и оттуда вытащить параметр `maxQuantity`.

Comment: А как вы его получаете? Такое впечатление, что вы его как текст получаете и мучаетесь потом с парсингом вместо чтобы получить именно как `json` и просто обращаться к его элементам.

Comment: @CrazyElf Этот HTML находится в html страницы, когда переходишь в корзину ozon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно примерно так

```
import json
j1 = json.loads(text)
for text2 in j1['state']['trackingPayloads'].values():
    j2=json.loads(text2)
    if 'items' in j2:
        for item in j2['items']:
            if 'maxQuantity' in item:
                print(item['maxQuantity'])
```

З.Ы. "Помогите, пожалуйста, отблагодарю." : "Моя благодарность не будет иметь границ, в разумных пределах" :)

Comment: Вы действительно применили этот код на json, который я предоставил?
Я не на столько глуп, написать ```j1 = json.loads(text)```. На этом моменте и возникают ошибки.

Comment: Ну на вашем образце все сработало. Может, на других что-то не так...

Comment: сохраните json по ссылке, которая в вопросе.
В коде прочитайте его и попробуйте выполнить ```j1 = json.loads(text)```

Comment: Сейчас отключаюсь до вечера, вижу какую-то проблему, пока не разобрался. Я проверял (и сработало!) так `text='''копипаст весь json из примера'''`

Comment: попробовал, не работает)

Comment: Ну ели ещё интересно.... Скачал Ваш пример в виде файла и успешно запустил свой код, получая текст таким вот кривым образом: `text = open(r'C:\Users\Alex\PycharmProjects\SO_tests\EiXE4mT2.txt', encoding='utf-8').read()`
 `text = ast.literal_eval("'" + text + "'")`

Comment: Я все таки победил этот json, но немного применил колхоза.
Но мне не дает покоя, как у вас получается запустить код). Вот что я делаю: ```import json
import ast


with open('json.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()

text = ast.literal_eval("'" + text + "'")

print(text)``` Но все равно получаю ошибку  ```SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139218/discussion-between-alex-titov-and-andreyru02).